# Multisite wont load stylesheet on second site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, .htaccess

*I've posted this four days ago to wordpress support, but no answer. Thought I'd might give it a go here as well. Copy+paste;*

Hi!
I'm trying to set up a multisite network for my portfolio.
Here's what I've got

Main site:

http://wp-sandbox.andreaswikstrom.com/

http://wp-sandbox.andreaswikstrom.com/two/

As you can see; The stylesheet on the second site doesn't load. I've tried to change my htaccess-file to all sorts of configurations but no results.

Also, when I try to access the dashboard for site two, I only get a "This webpage has a redirect loop"-message.

Here's the htaccess-code under network settings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp-sandbox/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wp-sandbox/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Is it not just a problem with the relative path?

Comment: In the 2nd site's case, Wordpress is looking for resources in `/two/wp-content`, `/two/wp-admin`, etc - which is returning 404's. Have you followed the steps detailed here: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Comment: Yes, that was the guide I was using when installing the multisite. Tried it again and I still get the same error.